# Why can't I use a tuple constant as a case in a switch statement

Tags: swift, switch-statement, tuples, constants

I decided to play with Swift case statements and tuples. It looks like one of the cooler features of the language.

I decided to play with month/day/year tuples. To my surprise, I can't use a constant tuple value as a case in a switch statement. Here is an example (can be pasted into a Playground and run)

```
import UIKit
typealias mdyTuple = (month: Int, day: Int, year: Int)
let joesBirthday: mdyTuple = (month: 6, day: 7, year: 1978)
let someday: mdyTuple = (6, 7, 1978)

switch someday
{
  //---------
  //The line "case joesBirthday" won't compile.
  //case joesBirthday:
  //  println("Joe was born on this day"
  //---------
case (joesBirthday.month, joesBirthday.day, joesBirthday.year):
  println("Joe was born on this day")
case (joesBirthday.month, joesBirthday.day, let year):
  println("Joe is \(year-joesBirthday.year) today")
default:
  println("Some other day")
}
```

The commented out code, `case joesBirthday:`, will not compile (in Xcode 6.3, if that matters). The case below (where I list all the elements of the joesBirthday tuple separately) which is both harder to type, and harder to read, does work)

My Playground crashed Xcode when typing this up, and crashed AGAIN trying to restart Xcode, so I'm having trouble reporting the error code.

Ok, I finally got Xcode to stop crashing (after 4 crashes in a row. Yayyy!) The error is "Binary operator `~=` cannot be applied to two mdyTuple operands."

Why is it trying to use the `~=` operand? Aren't like tuples equatable?

Is there some **clean** alternative syntax that lets me use a constant tuple in a case of a switch statement?

Comment: what if you use tuple index in switch?

Comment: like `case (joesBirthday.0, joesBirthday.1, joesBirthday.2):`?  Sure, that works, but that's no better than the named elements syntax. I want to list a tuple constant as a case value directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement the `~=` operator for the `mydTuple` type like this:

```
func ~=(a: mdyTuple, b: mdyTuple) -> Bool {
    return a.month ~= b.month && a.year ~= b.year && a.day ~= b.day
}
```

That worked for me in a Playground... Now, this code

```
switch someday {
case joesBirthday:
    println("one")
default:
    println("two")
}
```

prints "one".

This is the operator's definition:

```
infix operator ~= {
    associativity none
    precedence 130
}
```

and is implemented for the following:

```
/// Returns `true` iff `pattern` contains `value`
func ~=<I : IntervalType>(pattern: I, value: I.Bound) -> Bool
func ~=<T>(lhs: _OptionalNilComparisonType, rhs: T?) -> Bool
func ~=<T : Equatable>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool
func ~=<I : ForwardIndexType where I : Comparable>(pattern: Range<I>, value: I) -> Bool
```

Comment: That does work. Cool. (voted) I'm still a little vague on what the ~= operator does and how it works with case statements.

Comment: This is a good explanation of the ~= operator:
http://austinzheng.com/2014/12/17/custom-pattern-matching/

Comment: It is the "pattern matching operator", I assume the switch statement is using it... The comment in the code briefly explains what it does.

Comment: Why do you need to use ~= in the implementation of the function? Wouldn't `return a.month == b.month && a.year == b.year && a.day == b.day` work and be simpler/faster-executing?

Comment: @DuncanC In this case I think you could use the `==` operator because the elements are `Int`, but would it be the same for, say, `String`? This implementation seems "safer"

Comment: Since the function you've written is specifically for comparing mdyTuple objects then == should be safe though, correct?