# Getting "Binary operator ~= cannot be applied to two (Int, Int) operands" in Swift switch statement with (Int, Int) tuple cases

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, foundation

I have a `UITableViewController` with a private `enum` called `IndexPath` as a nested type.

```
class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController {

    enum IndexPath {
        case Gender, Weight, EmergencyContact

        var tuple: (Int, Int) {
            switch self {
            case .Gender:
                return (0, 0)

            case .Weight:
                return (0, 1)

            case .EmergencyContact:
                return (1, 0)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The point of this is so that inside my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I can simply put the section and row in a tuple and make a switch statement to match the enum values. That way, I get to do customise the cell as I should for that index path:

```
switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
case IndexPath.Gender.tuple:
    // Do something.

case IndexPath.Weight.tuple:
    // Do something.

case IndexPath.EmergencyContact.tuple:
    // Do something.

default:
    break;

}
```

However, I keep getting a compiler error `Binary operator ~= cannot be applied to two (Int, Int) operands` on the lines where the switch cases are. Any idea what that means? I'm not even aware of an operator `~=` and neither am I explicitly using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677991/why-cant-i-use-a-tuple-constant-as-a-case-in-a-switch-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this.

```
  switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
    case (IndexPath.Gender.tuple.0, IndexPath.Gender.tuple.1):
         // Do something.

    case (IndexPath.Weight.tuple.0, IndexPath.Weight.tuple.1):
        // Do something.

    case (IndexPath.EmergencyContact.tuple.0, IndexPath.EmergencyContact.tuple.1):
        // Do something.

    default:
        break;

    }
```

Comment: If it helped you, can accept as correct answer. It will help others too.:)