# Swift tuple switch case : pattern of type cannot match values of type

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, tuples

So I'm in the process of learning swift for a new job and working on a static table view and decided to try and use tuples to keep track of which cell has been selected. However I'm getting the following error:

> Expression pattern of type '(section: Int, row: Int)' cannot match values of type '(section: Int, row: Int)'

This error is a result of the following simplified code

```
    let ABOUTPROTECTIONCELL = (section: 1, row: 0)
    let cellIdentifier = (section: indexPath.section, row: indexPath.row)

    switch cellIdentifier {
    case ABOUTPROTECTIONCELL:
        print("here")
    default:
        print("bleh")
    }
```

What is really confusing is that when I use the following "if" statement instead of a switch statement everything works fine the program runs fine...

```
    if (cellIdentifier == CELL_ONE) {
        print("cell1")
    } else if (cellIdentifier == CELL_TWO) {
        print("cell2")
    } else if (cellIdentifier == CELL_THREE) {
        print("cell3")
    }
```

Is there a way to do this with a switch statement as I find that more elegant than the if statement? Very curious as to why this doesn't work as is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code does not compile because tuples are not `Equatable`. See [Why can't I use a tuple constant as a case in a switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677991/why-cant-i-use-a-tuple-constant-as-a-case-in-a-switch-statement).

Comment: If they aren't equatable why does the if statement compile and run? That's whats confusing me.

Comment: There is a `==` operator for tuples, but tuples do not conform to a protocol. – Also: The Equatable protocol guarantees the existence of a `== operator`, but a `==` operator does not imply conformance to Equatable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
let ABOUTTROVPROTECTIONCELL = (section: 1, row: 0)
let cellIdentifier = (section: indexPath.section, row: indexPath.row)

switch cellIdentifier {
case (ABOUTTROVPROTECTIONCELL.section, ABOUTTROVPROTECTIONCELL.row):
    print("here")
default:
    print("bleh")
}
```

**Solution 2**

Just use `IndexPath` struct and its initializer for creating `ABOUTTROVPROTECTIONCELL`

```
let ABOUTTROVPROTECTIONCELL = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
let cellIdentifier = indexPath // Not necessary, you can just use indexPath instead

switch cellIdentifier {
case ABOUTTROVPROTECTIONCELL:
    print("here")
default:
    print("bleh")
}
```

**Solution 3**

Implement `~=` func for your tuple:

```
typealias IndexPathTuple = (section: Int, row: Int)
func ~=(a: IndexPathTuple, b: IndexPathTuple) -> Bool {
    return a.section ~= b.section && a.row ~= b.row
}

let ABOUTTROVPROTECTIONCELL = (section: 1, row: 0)
let cellIdentifier = (section: indexPath.section, row: indexPath.row)

switch cellIdentifier {
case ABOUTTROVPROTECTIONCELL:
    print("here")
default:
    print("bleh")
}
```

Comment: Your first case can be re-written like `switch cellIdentifier {
case (ABOUTTROVPROTECTIONCELL.section, ABOUTTROVPROTECTIONCELL.row):`

Comment: @MidhunMP, yes, thank you.