# How to use a tuple as a pattern in a switch statement

Tags: swift, tuples, pattern-matching

Is it possible to use a tuple as a pattern in a switch statement?

In the sample code below I'd like to define a named constant to represent a pattern to match against, in this case the tuple (1,2)

```
let thing = 1
let otherThing = 2
let patternToMatchAgainst = (1,2)

switch (thing, otherThing) {
  case patternToMatchAgainst: break // Expression pattern of type '(Int, Int)' cannot match values of type '(Int, Int)'
  default: break
}
```

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677991/why-cant-i-use-a-tuple-constant-as-a-case-in-a-switch-statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:
case (patternToMatchAgainst.0,patternToMatchAgainst.1):